Is there a way to create a dependency between two search fields in odatav2 preview using RAP?
I'm quite new to RAP development and would like some help.
The requirement is to create a dependency between an Amount field and its Currency field. If the user inputs the amount field and tries to execute the filters by clicking 'Go' in the preview, it should stop the execution and display the message 'Currency field is empty'.
I have tried using a Behavior Definition, but it only works to validate the data for Create, Delete, and Update and not for the filters the user has used.
I have also tried an Unmanaged Query and was able to extract the filters from the preview and prevent the data from displaying when the user only inputs the Amount, but I'm not sure how to display the message in the preview afterward.

To raise a message in your if_behav_impl~query implementation
 METHODS:
      query_impl FOR if_behav_impl~query IMPORTING keys result context.

you can bring the message out by using the context member, i.e.
context->add_message ( ... iv_msgty = 'E'..) 


You Can achieve this using Prechecks or validation methods(draft-enabled application).

Using Prechecks: This will only trigger the validations when you press the save or create button.
Using Validations: triggers after pressing the Enter key or the create or save button.
For this, your application should be draft-enabled.
Try This: SAP Link


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
